# how to access mySQL server in kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have created a MySQL deployment in kubernetes and exposed it as nodes-port.

***What I can do:***
Access it from inside the cluster using
`kubectl run -it --rm --image=mysql:5.6 --restart=Never mysql-client -- mysql -h mysql -ppassword`

**What I want to do:**
Access the MySQL server from outside the cluster(like accessing a normal MySQL server).
Kubernetes v1.13 in DigitalOcean Cloud.
Guide me, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it by `mysql -u {username} -p {password} -h {any kubernetes worker ip} -P {nodePort}`. After you start mysql container and expose it ad node port through a service.

Comment: its asking for a password @hansika

Comment: give your mysql root password. Did you specify any password when you deploy mysql?

Comment: `mysql -u {username} -p  -h {any kubernetes worker ip} -P {nodePort}` worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD while bringing up the pod.  How were you able to bring it up in Docker without it?